# Why does align-items not center this text vertically?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

*EDIT: It appears this problem only occurs on Mac Firefox (I tested on version 107), and is likely a bug specific to that browser.*

In the snippet below, I am using the `display:flex; align-items: center` trick to center some large text vertically.  However, there is extra space at the bottom:

[image: extra space]

There is no padding, and I can't figure out what is causing the lack of symmetry.  I've also tried removing the `<span>`, and adjusting `line-height`, but neither of those worked either.

How can I make the text appear centered between the top and bottom border lines.  Of course I can add `padding-top` to compensate manually, but I'd like a solution that actually solves the problem and would scale with text size.

Here is a snippet demonstrating the problem:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
<span>$0.00</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks perfectly centered in Safari. So make sure any corrections you apply don't ruin that.

Comment: Same in firefox

Comment: also in chrome. are you on zoom 100% ?

Comment: I am on Firefox 107.0 on Mac (latest version).  I was zoomed a bit for that screenshot but I just changed zoom to 100% and it still has extra space on the bottom.

Comment: I can confirm the problem in Firefox/MacOS as well.

Comment: Consider opening an issue over at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi, providing your reproducer.

Comment: These sorts of problems are usually caused by other code that is present in the project, but not included in the Stack post.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin That is why I included a snippet to reproduce.  It reproduces exactly on Firefox Mac as described.  It is not caused by other code.

Comment: Got it. (I posted that comment before you edited the question to include that piece of info.)

Comment: Duplicateish: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image/5804278#5804278 — it **is** vertically centred, the text just doesn't contain any characters with descenders such as `y`, `p` or `g`

Comment: @Quentin, No, it isn't.  Please read the edit.